# open camera in webview (ios 14, ionic)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, camera, wkwebview, capacitor

I am developing an application with ionic, I want to open the camera to run a tensorlfowjs model.

Ionic packages html and javascript files in a native application and executes them in a webview, with the web version and the android version I have no problems.
But in the version for ios it is giving me a lot of problems opening the camera from the webview.

```
 let video: HTMLVideoElement =  document.getElementById("vid") as HTMLVideoElement;
    var mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
    mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({
              video: true,
              audio: true,
            })
            .then((stream) => {
  
              // Changing the source of video to current stream.
              video.srcObject = stream;
              video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
                video.play();
              });
            })
            .catch(error=>console.error('error open camera', error));
```

I have added the permissions for the camera in info.plist, when I run that code it shows a alert requesting permission for the camera the first time, but I always get an empty error message in the js code

```
 [error] - error open camera  {}
```

I am testing with a device with IOS: 14.4.2 this https://pastebin.com/Dx44XMYY is the system log. where you can see the following message

```
pp  UserMediaPermissionRequestManagerProxy::denyRequest(F6CC2F45DD55FA12) 15, reason: InvalidConstraint
```

I do not know how to move forward, what to try, or what the reason for the error may be.
I appreciate any advice

**Edit**: As @jcesarmobile says, it seems to be ios 14 problem, I have tested the code with ios 15 and it works. I appreciate any advice on how to fix it

Comment: Why are you accessing Camera via navigator.mediaDevices; when there are native plugins available ?

Comment: With native plugins it is difficult to have control of how the camera is rendered, most of them open a native screen, I also don't have a data stream of what the camera sees to do the classification in real time.

Comment: use Camera Preview plugin instead: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera-preview for Capacitor: https://github.com/capacitor-community/camera-preview

Comment: with camera preview I don't have a data stream of what the camera sees to use tensorflow js in real time. This library gives you a photo, but you dont have control, for example you cant put the stream in a video tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting audio to true, you also need the [microphone usage description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsmicrophoneusagedescription)

`NSMicrophoneUsageDescription`

Comment: yes, I have NSMicrophoneUsageDescription and I try with audio: false, but the behavior is the same

Comment: then it might be a bug on iOS 14.4.2, it's working fine for me on iOS 15

Comment: effectively, it is a problem of ios 14, with ios 15 it works.